# Unit Testing a Function That Calls a url with Mock

Tags: python

## Question

I have a function that calls a url and then modifies that url's response. How can I write a unit test for the portion of that function's code that modifies the response, without having to rely on that url?

### Example

#### my_module.py

```
import requests

def get_some_resource():
    url = 'http://httpbin.org/get'
    r = requests.get(url)
    # Special manipulation of returned text (what I want to test) simple example used
    output = r.text.upper()
    return output
```

### What I've tried so far

- Using mock's MagicMock() (you can't use it to override a function's variables, as far as I can tell)
- I've considered breaking apart the two sections of that function (the retrieval of the url and the modify of the response), however, I'm not clear if that's necessary
- So much googling my hands hurt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a unit test, you would just probably want to mock out the `requests` library. You can either just `patch` the whole thing, or just `get`, it doesn't really matter.

It'd look like:

```
get = mock.Mock()
text = get.return_value.text = "hey I got this")
with mock.patch("my_module.requests.get", get):
    resource = get_some_resource()
self.assertEqual(resource, text.upper())
```

Cheers.

Comment: It is for a unit test, I should have mentioned that. Thanks very much!